# Find $N$ in sequence, so that $|x_n - 1| < 0.01$, when all $n > N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$x_n = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}}$$

I get the idea that for $x_n$, $x_n > 0.99$ and $x_n < 1.01$ , but just can't prove it mathematicly;

Is it linked to $|x_n - \text{limit}| = x_N < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Your question is difficult to read because it is not written using MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1$, obviously such a number $N$ exists. To find it explicitly assume that $|x_n - 1| < 0.01$, then:

$$|x_n -1| = \left|\frac{n - \sqrt{n^2 + n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right| = \left|\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac 1n}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n}}\right| < \left|1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac 1n}\right| = \sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1$$

Now make the last term less than $0.01$ and we have:

$$\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1 < 0.01 \implies \sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} < 1.01 \implies 1 + \frac 1n < 1.0201 $$
$$\implies \frac 1n < 0.0201 \implies n > 49.75$$

Therefore choosing $N=50$ is sufficient.